# Problems returning heart rate values using `HKAnchoredObjectQuery` on Series 5 Watch and Watch OS6

Tags: swift, apple-watch, healthkit, watchos, heartrate

I am using `HKAnchoredObjectQuery` to query for heart rates as I would prefer not to use the WorkoutBuilder API for this app.  This query has always returned heart rates during a workout at normal sample rates (per second etc) but I noticed that while testing on a Series 5 Watch OS 6.1 I am only seeing very sporadic samples e.g. 5 heart rates taken in an hour.  There is nothing in the documentation for `HKAnchoredObjectQuery` that it is being deprecated.  Any idea why this method of heart rate collection is no longer working?

```
    func startHeartRateQuery(from startDate: Date, updateHandler: @escaping ([HKQuantitySample]) -> Void) {
        let typeIdentifier = HKQuantityTypeIdentifier.heartRate
        startQuery(ofType: typeIdentifier, from: startDate) { _, samples, _, _, error in
            guard let quantitySamples = samples as? [HKQuantitySample] else {
                print("Heart rate query failed with error: \(String(describing: error))")
                return
            }
            updateHandler(quantitySamples)

        }
    }


   //Generic helper function 
    private func startQuery(ofType type: HKQuantityTypeIdentifier, from startDate: Date, handler: @escaping
        (HKAnchoredObjectQuery, [HKSample]?, [HKDeletedObject]?, HKQueryAnchor?, Error?) -> Void) {
        let datePredicate = HKQuery.predicateForSamples(withStart: startDate, end: nil, options: .strictStartDate)
        let devicePredicate = HKQuery.predicateForObjects(from: [HKDevice.local()])
        let queryPredicate = NSCompoundPredicate(andPredicateWithSubpredicates:[datePredicate, devicePredicate])

        let quantityType = HKObjectType.quantityType(forIdentifier: type)!

        let query = HKAnchoredObjectQuery(type: quantityType, predicate: queryPredicate, anchor: nil,
                                          limit: HKObjectQueryNoLimit, resultsHandler: handler)
        query.updateHandler = handler
        healthStore.execute(query)

        activeDataQueries.append(query)
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Strange but it turns out I had Workout Power Saving Mode set to on in the Watch App's settings.  Unless I set by accident it was set to on when I installed Watch OS 6? After turning it off the heart rate queries are returning normally again.